# detecting div scroll bar reach end by jquery

Tags: jquery

when the below code run then browser hang. here is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/CenterDiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Main').center();
        $('#Main').bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                //var new_div = '<div class="new_block"></div>';
                //$('.main_content').append(new_div.load('/path/to/script.php'));
                alert("end");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.centered
{
    height:640px;
    width:700px;
    border-color:Black;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    overflow:scroll
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="Main" class="centered">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

actually the code which causes browser hang is

```
$('#Main').bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
                //var new_div = '<div class="new_block"></div>';
                //$('.main_content').append(new_div.load('/path/to/script.php'));
                alert("end");
            }
        });
```

by the above code i was trying to detect that scroll bar drag to end of div or not. why i am getting error....please advise. thanks

Comment: if i comment alert then code works fine. so why problem is coming for alert? any one can say....help.

Comment: No errors here:  http://jsfiddle.net/HDuzr/